# Apple Watch Series 3 refusing to charge only at night

Tags: apple-watch, watchos

I unplugged my watch (watchOS 8, Series 3, 38mm, Bought in 2020) yesterday and put it on. It was on nightstand mode with the clock & green lightning bolt indicating it was charging (the screen was on all night though, I don't know why). I got a 10% low power alert at 8am, an hour after I put it on.

I threw it back on its charger (the one it came with), and I got really ticked off.
I checked it this morning & put it on, and it was already down to 95%, indicating it charged, but stopped at night.

The battery graph in Settings doesn't even show it was charging at all.

How can I fix this?! It's really frustrating.

Comment: Hardware problems are very difficult to troubleshoot in this type of forum.  Usually when this type of thing happens, you reboot the device.  If that doesn't fix it, un-pair and re-pair to your iPhone.  If none of those work, contact Apple Support.